# MongoDB sub-query

Tags: mongodb, join, subquery, aggregate, lookup

i'm trying to write a subquery in mongoDB.

i want to access data similar to this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pull_request_comment 
WHERE pull_request_id IN(SELECT id FROM pull_request                
WHERE repoid=32443 AND login="xyz");
```

i have two collections
 both are defined below.

db.pull_request.find().pretty()

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d14d7e0c69e2f56c049fbda"),
    "repoid" : NumberLong(32443),
    "prs" : [
        {
            "id" : NumberLong(287768173),
            "user" : {
                "login" : "xyz"
            },
        },
        {
            "id" : NumberLong(564e56),
            "user" : {
                "login" : "xyz"
            },
        },
                ]
}
```

db.pull_request_comment.find().pretty();

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d14ddb4c69e2f56c04a01ea"),
    "repoid" : NumberLong(32443),
    "user" : {
        "login" : "xyz"
    },
    "pullrequestid" : NumberLong(287768173),
         "comment": "please fix this"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d14ddb4c69e2f56c04a01ea"),
    "repoid" : NumberLong(32443),
    "user" : {
        "login" : "xyz"
    },
    "pullrequestid" : NumberLong(287768173),
         "comment": "write correct code"
}
```

i have tried with lookup but it returns all data. it's not working as expected.

```
db.pull_request_comment.aggregate([
   {

      $lookup:
         {
           from: "pull_request",
           let: { prid: "$pullrequestid"},
           pipeline: [
            {$unwind:"$prs"},
            { $match:
                        { $expr:
                            { $eq: [ "prs.id",  "$$prid" ] }                            
                        }
            },
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "repoid",'32443'] },
                         { $eq: [ "prs.user.login",  "chirag" ] },
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
           ],
           as: "stockdata"
         }
    }
])
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your repoid matching to string or NumberLong ?

Comment: @srinivas y  yes it's number long that's not an issue i have tried without single quotes also.

Answer (score 2):

I have re-writed the query

```
db.pull_request_comment.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "pull_request",
            let: { prid: "$pullrequestid" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: { "repoid": "32443"}
                },
                { $unwind: "$prs" },
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$prs.id", "$$prid"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {"prs.user.login": "xyz"}
                },
            ],
            as: "stockdata"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks but not working. it returns all data from the collection.

Comment: wait I'll fix this

Comment: Still it returns all data.